# Double action links

Tags: hyperlink, double, action

I am building business websites for multiple clients and I would like to be able to create  links that do two things at once. Specifically, when visitors click an image on the website, in addition to going to the location the link specifies, I would also like to send a pre-determined text to the business owner's cell phone.  Is this possible.

Comment: Please share code What have you tried??

Comment: Jatin, I haven't tried any code yet, I am in the research mode. I am just assuming it is possible from my limited knowledge of code.

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed possible. You'll need to call a php file with two parameters. One parameter should be the link where the user should be redirected, the other parameter would need to be the message you want to send to the owner.
i.e. your link would need to look like this:

```
 <a href="redirect.php?url=www.yourdomain.com/your-html.html&message=You+got+a+hit+on+your+link">link text or image</a>
```

Then you need to prepare your php to get these parameters. First you need to send the text message, (tutorial for this can be found on this link: http://davidwalsh.name/send-text-message , and after the message is sent you need to redirect to the link you've got from the parameter. In php, you can read the above sent parameters like

```
 $redirectlink = $_GET['url];
 $message = $_GET['message'];
```

I hope this helps you resolve your issue.